# Spreadsheet-like functionality in web app

Tags: spreadsheet, xml-spreadsheet

I have a web app for commercial property management that needs spreadsheet-like functionality for doing budgets. I don't want to use Google Sheets because my users won't necessarily have a Google account.

So is there anything out there that I could use?

I looked and could only find [SocialCalc](http://www.socialcalc.org/) which wasn't quite good enough for me.

**Options:**

[ExtJS](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) Grid Component (Open Source[GPL3] & Commercial License)

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) Grid Component (Commercial License)

TreeGrid (Commercial License, Free Version has maximum of [33 rows](http://www.coqsoft.com/TreeGrid5_7/Html/EJSTreeGrid.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind implementing the logic yourself, the [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) grid component is a JavaScript grid component with lots of powerful features, and it is available in both open-source and commercial versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have used dhtmlXGrid successfully. There is an open source version that you can use freely to get your application developed. Assuming everything works out, for $200 you can purchase a license for it and distribute it with your application.

Very easy to use; create an HTML table structure with your data in it and then bind dhtmlXGrid to the table - it automatically turns the table cells into editable fields.

Check it out here: http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid

Again, you will need to implement the spreadsheet logic yourself but dhtmlXGrid makes it straightforward to translate that into an editable column/row display.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent grid from [Farpoint](http://www.fpoint.com/)

They have web and win forms grids available and are not too bad price wise

Answer (score 0):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com) has spreadsheet-type functionality in their data grid product

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give a try to treegrid @ www.coqsoft.com .

Answer (score 0):

try telerik radgrid. It is a pretty decent .net user control which can easily render an XML datasource for user editting. Its also fully Ajax enabled to avoid delays when entering volumes of data.